# How to add class to only one of multiple same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three same items in the DOM. Exactly what I mean is a wobbling line `<span class="caret"></span>`

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-1">
   <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>  
   <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>  
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-2">
   <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>  
   <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>  
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-3">
   <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>  
   <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Scenario:
I click on the first `<span class="caret"></span>` gets the class `"open"`, and the rest still has only `"caret"`. I click on the second `<span class="caret"></span>` gets the class `"open"`, and in the first the class `"open"` is removed. Is it possible? I wrote something like this:

```
$(".caret").click(function () {
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
  if ($('.caret').data('clicked')) {
    $(".caret").toggleClass('opened');
  }
});
```

It works, but all `"caret"` classes get `toggleClass('opened')` and I just want it to get the one you click on...

Comment: That HTML is invalid. A span can not be a child of a UL. You have an unclosed anchor element

Comment: Please **fix** the invalid HTML.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer

Comment: I did mark answer. Thanks guys

Comment: write css for span like unset and set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid so it is going to produce wrong HTML Markup in the browser. Not knowing how you actually want it to look, I can not offer a solution on fixing it. Once you get it fixed, The basic code should be

```
$('.caret').on('click', function () {
    $('.caret.opened') // all the open carets
      .not(this) // removed the one that was clicked
      .removeClass('opened'); // remove the class
    $(this)
      .toggleClass('opened'); // toggle the one that was clicked
      //.addClass('opened'); // if you want it always open
});
```

if one always has to be opened

```
$('.caret').on('click', function () {
    $('.caret.opened') // all the open carets
      .removeClass('opened'); // remove the class
    $(this)
      .addClass('opened'); // set clicked to open
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I was also playing with the toggle the one clicked. I think OP likely wants one open at all times.

Comment: We know it is a simple addClass :)

Comment: Perfect solution for me @espascarello Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You were on the right track by using `$(this)` but then reverted back to using `$('.caret')`. Do this:

```
$(".caret").click(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('opened');
});
```

---

Askers request to close all other `.caret` classes:

```
$(".caret").click(function () {
    $(".caret").removeClass('opened');
    $(this).addClass('opened');
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. It's pretty good, but I have one more question. What should I do if I want to undo this action? So when my "span" opened, and I click on the second one, the first one would close. Can this be done on this code that I am currently writing?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, but i haven't finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you might have meant this

having a span in a UL is invalid HTML

```js
$(".nav-item a").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".caret").removeClass('opened');
  $(this).next(".caret").addClass('opened'); // could toggle if needed
});
```

```css
.caret::after { content: "" }
.opened::after { content: "" }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item" id="nav-1"><a href="#">ITEM</a><span class="caret"></span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item" id="nav-2"><a href="#">ITEM</a><span class="caret"></span></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item" id="nav-3"><a href="#">ITEM</a><span class="caret"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not needed for this unless you're already using it in other places in your project.

```js
const navItems = [...document.querySelectorAll("[class^=nav-item-")];

navItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const opened = document.querySelector(".opened");

    if (opened) {
      opened.classList.remove("opened");
    }

    item.parentElement.querySelector(".caret").classList.add("opened");
  });
});
```

```css
/* demo only */

.caret.opened:after {
  content: "opened";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-1">
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
  </li>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-2">
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
  </li>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-3">
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
  </li>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML needs correction. Something like below is syntactically more correct.
Let's add up CSS to show what caret looks like.

And then, in JavaScript, handle the toggle.

```js
$("ul").click(function (e) {
  var caret = $(this).find('.caret');
  $('.caret').data('clicked', false);
  $('.caret').removeClass('opened');

  caret.data('clicked', true);
  caret.toggleClass('opened');
});
```

```css
.caret {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.opened {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-1">
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>    
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-2">
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>    
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item-3">
    <a href="#">ITEM</a>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your HTML tag
missed anchor closing tag
add .nav class on each li

```
$(".nav").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).next('.caret').hasClass('clicked opened')) {
        $('.caret').removeClass('clicked opened');
    } else {
        $('.caret').removeClass('clicked opened');
        $(this).next('.caret').addClass('clicked opened');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n56b84t9/1/